# Contiki RPL and unicast DIO

Tags: simulation, iot, contiki, cooja

I'm trying to learn to use Contiki 3.x.

When launching the "rpl-collect" example in Cooja with one udp-sink and several udp-sender, I see that each sender node regularly unicast DIO message to its preferred parent (in addition of multicast DIO).

The only reason I see to this is either a response to a DIS or a probing mechanism, but there is no DIS message and I disabled probing and saw no change.

Maybe is it worth noting that every time a child node sends a DIO in unicast to its parent seems to be just after that child received a 802.15.4 ACK for a previous communication.

Does somebody knows why child node unicast DIO to their parents ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was the probing mechanism still running, I didn't disable it properly the first time !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is happening due to probing mechanism. The probing is either done using DIO or DIS message. In your case DIO probing must be enabled. 120 system clock seconds is the default interval of probing.

Comment: This is not a valid answer.